# How to say if 'value' isn't included in this data frame column (from this list of 'values'), add a row for it anyway, and put an NA in other column

Tags: r

Set up: I work with animals doing behavior tasks. I wrote a function to take my raw data and "clean it," basically, then I'm applying it to many different data sheets. This data has 20 subjects in it, we'll just say K1, K2... K20.

Occasionally, the function I wrote removes a subject from the sheet completely. I know why this happens (basically, he didn't do anything at all one day and gets filtered out by something the function does at one point). Now, I have been going in an "spot fixing" this when it happens, but this brings me to my question.

Really, all I'm doing in my spot fixing is making the animal stay in the final spreadsheet where his value for whatever column he got filtered out from ends up being a 0 or an NA (whichever is applicable to each situation, eg a 0 for a frequency or an NA for a reaction time, for example).

BUT, is there a way I can do this on the back end instead.

I get my "cleaned" data frame after my function that should have 20 animals (K1-K20), but it only has 19 (e.g. missing K3).

How would I write a function saying:

"if 'Subject' isn't included in this data frame (from this list of 'Subjects'?), add it anyway, and put an NA in this other column for them"

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to have the structure of your main data frame and the data frame you want to include from. It can be obtained with str().

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP has created datasets where *rows* are missing for one or more `Subject`s and he wants to complete the rows according to the list of `Subjects`.

This can be solved in different ways. My preferred way is by *joining* or *merging*. Another approach is to use the `complete()` function. There are some subtle differences in the output of the different approaches.

But first we need to create suitable sample data.

#### Create sample data

```
# complete vector of all subjects
Subjects <- sprintf("K%02i", 1:10) 
# data.frame with subject K03 missing
DF <- droplevels(data.frame(Subject = Subjects,
                            value = seq_along(Subjects) / 10)[-3L, ])

Subjects
```

> ```
>  [1] "K01" "K02" "K03" "K04" "K05" "K06" "K07" "K08" "K09" "K10"
> ```

```
DF
```

> ```
>    Subject value
> 1:     K01   0.1
> 2:     K02   0.2
> 3:     K04   0.4
> 4:     K05   0.5
> 5:     K06   0.6
> 6:     K07   0.7
> 7:     K08   0.8
> 8:     K09   0.9
> 9:     K10   1.0
> ```

Note that `Subject` is a factor and `K03` is missing from the factor levels as well (thanks to `droplevels()`)

```
str(DF)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ Subject: Factor w/ 9 levels "K01","K02","K04",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>  $ value  : num  0.1 0.2 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1
> ```

#### base R `merge()`

```
merge(data.frame(Subject = Subjects), DF, all.x = TRUE)
```

> ```
>    Subject value
> 1      K01   0.1
> 2      K02   0.2
> 3      K03    NA
> 4      K04   0.4
> 5      K05   0.5
> 6      K06   0.6
> 7      K07   0.7
> 8      K08   0.8
> 9      K09   0.9
> 10     K10   1.0
> ```

The row for `K03` has been completed.

Please note that `Subject` is still a factor after `merge()` but has also completed the factor levels:

> ```
> 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ Subject: Factor w/ 10 levels "K01","K02","K03",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>  $ value  : num  0.1 0.2 NA 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1
> ```

#### SQL

```
S <- data.frame(Subject = Subjects)
sqldf::sqldf("select * from S left natural join DF")
```

The printed output is similar to above but `Subject` has been coerced to type character, silently:

> ```
> 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ Subject: chr  "K01" "K02" "K03" "K04" ...
>  $ value  : num  0.1 0.2 NA 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1
> ```

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[.(Subject = Subjects), on = "Subject"]
```

The printed output is the same as above but `Subject` has been coerced to type character, silently.

#### dplyr

```
dplyr::right_join(DF, data.frame(Subject = Subjects))
# or
dplyr::left_join(data.frame(Subject = Subjects), DF)
```

Both return a data.frame with `Subject` coerced to type character and print a warning:

> Column `Subject` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
>   character vector

#### tidyr::complete()

```
tidyr::complete(DF, Subject = Subjects)
```

returns a tibble and prints a warning:

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 2
>    Subject value
>    <chr>   <dbl>
>  1 K01       0.1
>  2 K02       0.2
>  3 K03      NA  
>  4 K04       0.4
>  5 K05       0.5
>  6 K06       0.6
>  7 K07       0.7
>  8 K08       0.8
>  9 K09       0.9
> 10 K10       1  
> Warning message:
> Column `Subject` joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector
> ```